# “attempt to use zero-length variable name” error when trying to load data

Tags: r

I've been trying to load the dataset for my first Kaggle notebook, but i keep getting error messages.

This is the code below:

```
heart_rate<- read_csv("/kaggle/input/fitbit-tracking-data/fitbit_data")

View(heart_rate)
```

Error Output below:

Error in parse(text = x, srcfile = src): attempt to use zero-length variable name
Traceback:

Comment: 'read_csv("/kaggle/input/fitbit-tracking-data/fitbit_data")' You have to be careful about paths. `/kaggle/input/...` means you have a directory at the top of your directory hierarchy that is named `kaggle` and you want to start the looking for the file in the `input` directory in that `kaggle` directory and then drill down further. You may mean `kaggle/input/...` instead? The lack of the `/` at the start means you are specifying a relative path from the current working directory. In other words, an absolute path is what you have in your post and you may mean to use relative?

Comment: There is probably some code that you are not showing us, which is giving you that error message.

Comment: Have you tried to eliminate some potential sources of error? Have you tried reading the file with any other applications, have you tried reading a known good .csv file from the same directory? Basic trouble-shooting stuff

Comment: I even tried changing my working directory, and i still got the same code error above.

Comment: Thanks guys it was a small mistake,  i had this on my code (  ```{r} ```)  when it should've just been the code itself. For example: ``` {r} library (skimr )''' wouldn't work on the notebook, but if you try library (skimr) without the bacticks it works immediately.